# try..catch errors in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, automation, try-catch

I am trying to automate mongodb setup and create users via a js script in mongo shell.

i tried to create the admin user and i want to check if the user is already created. If i run create user if the user already exists, it throws error. SO i want to check if the user is there already

```
#init.js
use admin
try {
db.createUser({
"user":"admin",
"pwd":"paddowrd",
"roles":[{"role":"root", "db":"admin"}]
});
}
catch (err) {
print ("Admin user already created");
db.auth("admin","paddowrd");
}




mongo < init.js
```

output:[error]

2019-06-06T14:07:58.039+0000 E QUERY [js] SyntaxError: missing catch or finally after try @(shell):2:0

Answer (score 1):

the proper command would be:

```
mongo --host localhost:27027 init.js
```

No need to redirect input here. Mongo command line accepts javascript file name as an argument.

also, get rid of the first two lines in the script and use db.getSiblingDB("admin") to switch databases.

```
//#init.js
//use admin
db.getSiblingDB("admin")
try {
db.createUser({
"user":"admin",
"pwd":"paddowrd",
"roles":[{"role":"root", "db":"admin"}]
});
}
catch (err) {
print ("Admin user already created");
db.auth("admin","paddowrd");
}
```

Comment: If i get rid of "use admin" it wont know which db to use.

Comment: If you need to do so, you can use db.getSiblingDB("admin") to switch databases, instead of use admin. See more at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/